# Select max date that the value needs reference field in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm confused about how to join two tables.

First table, called **t_logging** must be used to select max date. Here's my code for that

```
select d.* from
(
  select ID,RFID, XD1,XD2,XN1,XN2,XS1,XS2,
    rank() over(partition by ID order by XD1 desc) seq
  from t_logging where id LIKE '%73%'
) d
where seq = 1;
```

And this is the result,

```
ID     XD1          XN1 
-----------------------
734    17-DEC-14    223
735    18-DEC-14    223
```

This **XN1** and **ID** need reference value from table **t_cluster**. These are the records of **t_cluster**.

```
ID       NAME       DESC 
----------------------------
223       A         Admin
734       B         Customer
735       C         Customer
736       D         Customer
```

I want the result as below.

```
ID       NAME     DESC         XD1
-----------------------------------------------
223       A       Admin        null
734       B       Customer     17-DEC-14
735       C       Customer     18-DEC-14
736       D       Customer     null
```

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT a.id,desc,d.* FROM t_cluster_odp a,(
  select d.* from
  (
    select ID, XD1,XN1,
      rank() over(partition by ID order by XD1 desc) seq
    from t_logging where id LIKE '%73%'
  ) d
  where seq = 1
) d
WHERE a.id LIKE '%73%';
```

But it doesn't give me the correct result. How do I join these two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but you should be able to do something like this

```
SELECT
 t_cluster.id,
 t_cluster.name,
 t_cluster.desc,
 t_logging_max.xd1
FROM
 t_cluster
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
  SELECT id, MAX(xd1) AS xd1
  FROM t_logging
  GROUP BY id
 ) t_logging_max ON t_cluster.id = t_logging_max.id
WHERE 
 t_cluster.id LIKE '%73%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it through subquery and `FULL OUTER JOIN` or `Left join` (which i saw from your desired output)

```
select 
 a.id,a.desc,d.id,d.xd1
from 
FROM t_cluster_odp a
LEFT JOIN
  (select *
   from
    (
      select ID,XD1,
        rank() over(partition by ID order by XD1 desc) seq
      from t_logging where id LIKE '%73%'
    )
   where seq = 1
  ) d
ON a.ID = d.ID
```